# JPA provider uses the wrong database type for collection table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

My JPA entity has  a map, where key - the other entity, value - boolean type.
It's defined as:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "join_table_name",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name ="owner_entity_key_name") })
@MapKeyColumn(name = "other_entity_key_name")
@Column(name = "name_for_boolean")
private Map<OtherEntity, Boolean> map;
```

Both the owner entity (where map is defined) and the other entity (that is used as a key in the map) have `@Id Integer id;` field.

In integration tests the jpa provider uses the following create table query:

```
create table join_table_name (
owner_entity_key_name integer not null, 
name_for_boolean boolean, 
other_entity_key_name binary(255) not null, 
primary key (owner_entity_key_name, name_for_boolean))
```

As you see the type of the `other_entity_key_name` is `binary(255)`, but not `integer` as I expect.

Any ideas why it works in such manner?

JPA Provider:

Hibernate Core {4.1.6.Final}

PS:
I've used `columnDefinition = "integer"` to set type explicitly, but the issue is still open  cause it's not the best option, I hope.

PPS: now I'm getting an exception when the connection between entities is flushed:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error
>   converting
>   "X'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'
>   (join_table_name: other_entity_key_name INTEGER NOT NULL)";

For some reason instead of entity id some its presentation is used.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is a hint for the second problem.

You need to use @MapKeyJoinColumn and not @MapKeyColumn.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyColumn.html

> Specifies the mapping for the key column of a map whose map key is a
>   basic type

versus

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html

> Specifies a mapping to an entity that is a map key.

Comment: The MapKeyJoinColumn does not work correctly. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8905 I've already tried it.

Comment: That issue only relates to the naming of the column which has nothing to do with the behaviour you are seeing. Is the Key of your Map a basic type? No, it is an entity so, as the documentation clearly states, you need @MapKeyJoinColumn.